# Meaning of curly brackets with numbers around: $\{\log\lambda_i\}_1^n$

Tags: notation

I am studying for an exam and found this in the solutions:

> "... with canonical parameters $\{\log\lambda_i\}^n_1$".

Index $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. The professor that wrote the exam has retired. Does anyone know what the $1$ and $n$ might mean?

Comment: If you post the question and the complete answer someone may be able to help. As it is you provide too little context.

Comment: It is a general question. The subject is about exponential families if that helps. The sentence is "Full and regular exponential family with canonical parameter $\{log\lambda_i\}^n_1$ toghether with $log\phi$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I tried to [point out](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/627592) that $i$ is not capitalized in this example.

Comment: @ahorn A plain edit is not going to help OP (or not much). Instead I think you ought to mention things like this in comments, so the OP actually explicitly learns something from it. In any case, my edit wasn't based on your suggested one; it arose independently.

Comment: @Lord_Farin yes, your edit overrode my one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually indicates the range of your index parameter, $i$. Sometimes you will see it written more explicitly as 
$$\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n.$$
For more general index sets you may see something like
$$\{A_i\}_{i \in I}.$$
This is useful if your index set is uncountable, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is an indexed set. For example:
$$
\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}.
$$

Does this help?