# Where does the first term go in this partial derivative?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am reading this paper https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4329-practical-variational-inference-for-neural-networks.pdf and I cannot see where the first part of the partial derivative for equations 7 and 8 go. Here is equation 7 from the paper.

$$
L^C(\mathbf{\alpha}, \mathbf{w}) = W\ln2b + \frac{1}{b} \sum_{i=1}^W |w_i - \mu| + C \implies \frac{\partial L^C(\mathbf{\alpha}, \mathbf{w})}{\partial w_i} = \frac{sgn(w_i - \mu)}{b}
$$

Shouldn't there be a leftover term $\ln2b$ as a result of the derivative of the first term on the RHS?

Comment: No, because the derivative is w.r.t. $w_i$ which means $W\ln 2b$ is treated as a constant which, when differentiated, equals $0$.

Comment: but if $w_i$ is a component of $W$ then it would not be a constant, right? Is $W$ not a matrix here?

Comment: $W$ represents the [_index_ of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782800/meaning-of-curly-brackets-with-numbers-around-log-lambda-i-1n) $\boldsymbol{\mathrm w}$. See the last paragraph on page 1 of the paper.